# Same Schema within Schema in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var dirSchema = new mongoose.Schema([{type:String, 
                name:String, path:String, children:[dirSchema]}]);
```

I want to store this type of schema using nodejs in mongodb? It is just like a file system structure. How do i query into the collections if i have a path say /foo/bar/hello/123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember how I solved it then (2014) but it can be solved by using Graph lookup operation. The depth field can be used to identify the depth of the folder.

```
db.dirs.aggregate([ 
    { $match: {
      dirId: "foo"
    } }, 
    {$graphLookup:{
    from:"product", 
    startWith:"$_id", 
    connectFromField:"_id", 
    connectToField:"parentId",
    "depthField": "depth" 
    as:"children"
  }}])
```